# What are UI based tools available for accessing Hive database?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

We have HDInsight cluster and users want to access Hive database and Hive tables as a Client. We are looking for client based application which can be UI based, we don't want to give them Amabari URL as it has capability of Admin. so please suggests tools for us.

Comment: Can you not create a new user without admin privileges to use Hive View of Ambari?

Comment: You can use your favorite JDBC4-compliant SQL tool if you configure JDBC connection to Hive.

Answer (score 1):

**Hue** is a Web tool based to deal with `Hive`, `Impala` and `HDFS`.

You can do everything you want from Hue, create database and tables, query tables and so on....

Comment: it sucks big time

Answer (score 1):

You can install Hue into a HDInsight cluster using the Script Actions provided in your HDInsight cluster. Please see below.

[image]

Please only select "Head" node for the installation. This installs Hue on your HN0 head node at port 8888.

Then you can use any browser to type the URL in the format `http://<head_node_0_FQDN>:8888` to launch Hue Web UI in your browser. Upon first launch of the Web UI, Hue will prompt you to create an account which you can do by providing a username and password.

**HOWEVER**, please note that the version of Hue that gets installed by default using above steps, *DOES NOT* allow you to create any additional logins than the one you create at first login. And also remember that first login is a Super Admin login to Hue, thus anyone having access, have FULL DDL and DML access to your Hive layer.

As an alternative you can setup open source Hue manually in your cluster. Also if you want to provide fine grained authorization to your Hive data, you will need to setup [Apache Ranger](https://ranger.apache.org/) in your HDInsight cluster.